# Adjoining a root to a field that already has that element

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

I know that one can take an irreducible polynomial $f$ over a field $K$ and make an extension containing a root of $f$ by the construction $K[x]/(f)$. What happens if $f$ is in fact reducible? For example, what does $\mathbb Q(\sqrt2)[x]/(x^2 - 2)$ look like?

Apologies for the vague question. I guess I'm asking what kind of structure this is (for one, I can't tell if it's still a field). What parts of it depend on the nature of $f$ or $K$?

Comment: It will certainly not be a field (unless $f$ has degree $1$), because $f$ is reducible. If $f$ has a root $r$ in $K$, then $f = \left(x-r\right) g$ for some $g \in K\left[x\right]$ (because $f$ is divisible by $x-r$). Hence, if $r$ is only a simple root of $f$, then the Chinese Remainder Theorem yields that $K\left[x\right] / \left(f\right) \cong K\left[x\right]/\left(x-r\right) \times K\left[x\right]/\left(g\right) \cong K \times K\left[x\right]/\left(g\right)$. If $r$ is a multiple root of $f$, then the answer is more complicated (but this cannot happen when $f$ is irreducible ...

Comment: ... and $K$ has characteristic $0$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how satisfactory this answer is, but in general for commutative rings $k \subseteq K$ and a polynomial $f \in k[x]$, one has
$$K[x]/(f) \cong K \otimes_k k[x]/(f)$$
as a tensor product of $k$-algebras. So for your example this implies
$$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)[x]/(x^2-2) \cong \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2) \otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$$
which has zero divisors:
$$(\sqrt{2} \otimes 1 + 1 \otimes \sqrt{2})(\sqrt{2} \otimes 1 - 1 \otimes \sqrt{2}) = 2 \otimes 1 - 1 \otimes 2 = 0.$$

Comment: See Darij's comment $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)[x]/(x^2-2) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)\times \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$

Comment: Oh that's very nice, could you write or link to a proof of that?

Answer (score 0):

It won't be an integral domain since $(x - \sqrt{2})(x+\sqrt{2}) = x^2-2 = 0$ in the quotient. You'll end up with four square roots of $2$.